# Does the air conduct electricity?

Tags: particle-physics, condensed-matter, conductors

If the air is compressed at high pressure in a container, then the volume of the air is less, therefore the air molecules are close to each other.

If electricity is passed through the container, do the air moleclues conduct electricity or not?

Normally air does not conduct electricity because the molecules are too far away from eachother

Comment: Rubber is much more dense and still doesn't conduct electricity.

Answer (score 2):

Normally air is a very good insulator. That is, until the voltage across an air gap gets high enough to cause the air to break down (ionize) and then it becomes a very good conductor.

The breakdown voltage depends on a number of factors.

Paschen's law shows that, for a given gas and given electrode configuration (he used parallel metal plates), the breakdown voltage is proportional to the product of the gas pressure and electrode gap. According to Wikipedia, for a given electrode gap, the voltage necessary to cause an arc decreases as the pressure is reduced but then gradually increases exceeding its original value.

Since the air molecules are farther apart with decreased pressure, the decrease in breakdown voltage with a decrease in pressure is somewhat counter intuitive to what you would expect.

The explanation is rather complex and can be found in the following Wikipedia link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paschen%27s_law

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Bob D! My masters thesis from 40 years ago involved paschen, townsend and corona discharge in small air gaps at ambient P and T and this brought back some pleasant memories!

Comment: @nielsnielsen Hi Niels. I used Paschen in my training of our engineers in product safety testing, specifically, dielectric withstand testing of product insulation systems and the breakdown voltage for the air component of those systems as a function of air gap, atmospheric pressure, electrode configuration (homogeneous and inhomogeneous fields) etc., etc..